# Vertical side menu's collapse is not working

Tags: html, css

The page has a vertical sidemenu. It works fine when the page is maximized. When minimized i would like it to show/hide on click on the toggle icon, but nothing happens. The menu just doesnt show in my case.

(But here in the fiddle, it flashes though).

Where am i going wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/rk74g6w0/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid  navbar-container">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DS-Menu</a>
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target=".sidebar-collapse"> 
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse collapse col-sm-3 col-md-2 
                sidebar navbar-default navbar-static-side">
                <ul id="menu" class="nav nav-sidebar sidebar-collapse in">
                    <li class="active mainmenu"><a href="#">Menu 0 <span  
                       class="glyphicon arrow"></span></a>

                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">item 0.1</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">item 0.2</a>

                            </li>                                
                        </ul>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me the icon is working... Be sure to clock on the icon and not the "Result" square from jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect link. Updated it.Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-sidebar sidebar-collapse in">
```

By this:

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-sidebar">
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rk74g6w0/1/